# How to keep jQuery accordion disabled but still change its active state?

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion

I have a jQuery accordion defined like:

```
$("#acrd").accordion({
    autoHeight: false,
    header: '.navhead',
    alwaysOpen: true,
    navigation: true,
    collapsible: true,
    disabled: true
});
```

When a client clicks on a button, I call a function `DoSomething()`, like this:

```
function DoSomething(id) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "getapage.php?id="+id,
        cache: false
        }).done(function( html ) {
            if(html == 'OK') {
                $("#acrd").accordion({ active: 1 }); // doesn't work
            } else {
                alert("Give an error!");
            }
    });
}
```

But nothing happens when I click the button, I checked Firebug and there is no syntax error.

How can I accomplish this? (without enabling the accordion in the process, the client must not be able to change the accordion active state)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably meant to use the [`activate`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/#method-activate) method, which activates the specified content part:

```
$("#acrd").accordion("activate", 1);
```

However, that won't work while the accordion is disabled. So you need to write it as

```
$("#acrd").accordion("enable").accordion("activate", 1).accordion("disable");
```

Comment: you are right it is activate, but still has no effect, if i'd use a wrong option wouldn't that result in syntax error - i didn't get that

Comment: @Erik: Yeah, no syntax error. Also, you need to enable the accordion first (see edit).

Comment: No, you wouldn't get a syntax error because the syntax would still be correct. What you'd be doing is sending an extra variable to the accordion, which the accordion code would then ignore. It's like saying 'Look at that sheep in the tree' when you meant to say 'squirrel' instead. Technically there's nothing wrong with the syntax but it makes no sense to whoever's listening.

Comment: I tried the new code, now it works, the only problem is that the entire accordion gets disable and gray in color. I cannot use it after that.

Comment: @Erik: Then you can either remove the CSS rules that make the accordion greyed, or you can `.accordion("destroy")` and re-create it with the same options as before except for an additional `active: 1`.

Comment: yeah I tried that, but still this wont work because I need to disable it somewhere along the way and everytime I do (even if I destory it first) it colors gray and can't be used after that.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize a accordion with the active option specified.

```
$( "#acrd" ).accordion({ active: 2 , others.... });
```

then try your code...

Answer (score 0):

some thing like this , as document says  `Get or set the active option, after init.`  like this [jquery ui active](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/#option-active)

```
$( "#acrd" ).accordion( "option", "active", 2 );
```

Comment: this also had no effect. is it possible that jquery doesn't allow change the state if the accordion is disabled?

Answer (score 0):

If you want it permanently disabled, then this might be useful for you

```
$("#accordion h3").unbind("click");
```

Replace h3 with whatever element you are using as a clickable header. You can still change the tabs by activate method or by setting active option.

Soruce: [jQuery accordion: prevent pane from opening/cancel changestart event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2004869/jquery-accordion-prevent-pane-from-opening-cancel-changestart-event?answertab=votes#tab-top)